# How to return std::optional<myclass> from a function?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17

I seem to be missing something very simple. The following does not work:

```
#include <optional>

class Alpha {
    Alpha() { }
    Alpha(const Alpha& that) { }
    Alpha(Alpha&& that) { }
    ~Alpha() { }

    static std::optional<Alpha> go() {
        return Alpha();
    }
};
```

The errors that I get are:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "Alpha" to "std::optional<Alpha>" exists 
T in optional<T> must satisfy the requirements of Destructible 
'return': cannot convert from 'Alpha' to 'std::optional<Alpha>'
```

What am I missing and can you please explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made all your constructor private. The `std::optional` cannot move or copy your class. To fix this, simply do that:

```
class Alpha {
public: // <--- there
    Alpha() { }
    Alpha(const Alpha& that) { }
    Alpha(Alpha&& that) { }
    ~Alpha() {}

private:
    static std::optional<Alpha> go() {
        return Alpha();
    }
};
```

You can also use a `struct`, which is a class with public members by default.

Also, keep in mind that defaulted constructor and assignment operators are usually better and more performant in places where you'd just put empty ones.

Comment: Argh! Just skipped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Roxy one of the many reason I keep using structs ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot As far as I know, `struct` and `class` are identical except for the default access modifier. I'm curious what other reason you might have to prefer `struct`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see no point of using class. It just seem more verbose in most cases. public inheritance by default with structs is a bliss. Also, I always tend to put all the public part of my class on top.  So in the end, in most of cases, I end up with no public keyword, and only a private keyword for the private part (if any).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I understand that, and I can see why some developers might prefer it. But my question is regarding how you said "one of the many reasons", meaning there are a lot more reasons. I was wondering what those other reasons might be.

Comment: With `struct`, default is public for members, and for inheritance.  Those are the two reasons I prefer `struct` over `class`.  (With class I tend to put my private members at the beginning, and with struct I tend to put my private members at the end... which I also prefer.  But that's just me.)

Comment: *"Also, keep in mind that defaulted constructor are usually better and more performant."* - Doesn't sound correct to me. The point of `std::optional` is that you can later check if the optional holds valid content or not. That's only loosely related to a default constructor. And `std::optional` has perfect performance if you need the features it provides.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The constructor he wrote make using his class less optimized. For example, his move constructor is not `noexcept`, that makes the compiler unable to elide exception handling in optional, and disable the move constructor of `vector`. Also, many optimization are applied when a type is trivially copiable/moveable, especially in std::vector, which will simply copy the whole buffer instead of calling the constructor in loops. I'm sure there is a lot of other point why you want to use defaulted constructors, but these are the one I though about off the top of my head.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: You use a default constructor when an object of that type can exist in a meaningful way without additional information. You use no default constructor when that's not possible. It's all about semantics, not performance. `std::optional` is largely orthogonal to that; an empty string or a zero int has different semantics than an empty optional string or an empty optional int. Whether the OP's class should actually have a default constructor or not is impossible to tell without knowing what it's supposed to mean and which data members it really has.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Ah yes, I somehow read "default constructor" instead of "defaulted". Still, doesn't make much sense in this context because we don't know much about what the class really looks like and whether the constructor can be defaulted or not.

Comment: @ChristianHackl From what OP showed us, his class could be trivial if it was only for defaulted members. Also, the occasion you actually need to change the move or copy constructor are rare if you use RAII properly. The defaulted one will do just fine, and in most cases, better, just because they maintain triviality and has automatic noexcept.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I edited the answer, I thinks it cover your concern, can you tell me if it's this better?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Looks good to me, upvoted.

Comment: Assuming the OP actually has any members in their real class, the defaulted copy c'tor is better than `Alpha(const Alpha& that) { }` simply because it will actually copy the members instead of default initializing them :)